# setOnItemSelectedListener on custom spinner adapter doesnt work

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

Hi guys hope u can help me, I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my spinner, and I set the Adapter inside `onPostExecute()` in an `AsyncTask`. The problem is when I call the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` it doesn't recognize the click event. My spinner is like a dialog, it works ok, the list of items is showed in popup spinner but the item selector doesnt work.. I guess it's because I miss the Context inside `setOnItemSelectedListener()` but not sure about that.

Here is my code:

**onPostExecute**:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                pDialog.dismiss(); 

spinAdmin.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.opina_spinner_item_saf,safList));

                spinAdmin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"MyItem", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                });
            }
```

In the same `Activity` my Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) { 
            super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override 
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
            return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt); 
            }
        @Override 
        public View getView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) { 
            return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt); 
            }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) { 
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
            View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opina_spinner_item_saf, prnt, false); 

            TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner .findViewById(R.id.txt_spinner_item_saf); 
            main_text.setText(safList.get(position)); 

            return mySpinner;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Just a quick note (might not make any sense here): If you select last selected item then `onItemSelected` method won't get called.

Comment: The dialog spinner doesn't close after selecting an item.. any items got recognized

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
spinAdmin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: There must be something else.